# Как найти повторяющиеся слова в массиве?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Если в массиве имена животных повторяются, то нужно напротив этого имени написать, что оно не уникальное, а если не повторяются — то что уникальное.

Вот мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {"Name": pd.Series(['Myrchik','Barsik','Bobik','Vasya','Vasya','Vasya','Barsik']), 
     "test_unique": pd.Series([],dtype='object')}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df1.index)
print(df1.columns)
print(df1)
print(df1.test_unique)
#index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(test_unique,names=["first", "second"])
def test_func(df1):
  for i in df1.test_unique: 
    df1.test_unique.count(i) 
    if df1.test_unique.count(i)  > 1:
      return 'not_unique'
    else: 
      return 'unique'
      
test_unique = df1.apply(test_func, axis=1)
df1.test_unique = test_unique
test_unique.name = 'test_unique'
print(df1)
```

Но похоже, что таким способом я не могу проверить данные типа `object`.

Ошибка в функции `test_func`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html):

```
df1["test_unique"] = \
    np.where(df1["Name"].duplicated(keep=False), "not_unique", "unique")
```

результат:

```
In [152]: df1
Out[152]:
      Name test_unique
0  Myrchik      unique
1   Barsik  not_unique
2    Bobik      unique
3    Vasya  not_unique
4    Vasya  not_unique
5    Vasya  not_unique
6   Barsik  not_unique
```